# Is memsetting a element in an array correct?

Tags: c, pointers, static

Is memsetting a pointer in an array ok or am I just overwriting the pointers to the elements here? 
Is it better when I memset the whole memory area or the elements in the array?

For example:

```
....
struct pollfd fds[2];
int tmp = 0;

for(; tmp < sizeof(fds[0])/sizeof(fds); tmp ++) {
    memset(fds[tmp], 0x00, sizeof(fds[tmp]));
}
....
```

vs.

```
....
struct pollfd fds[2];

memset(fds, 0x00, sizeof(fds[tmp]));
....
```

Comment: "*... overwriting the pointers to the elements ...*" -- What pointers to the elements? An array object just contains a sequence of elements; there are no pointers to the elements unless you create them. Whether `memset`, either for a single element or for the entire array, makes sense depends on the contents of `struct pollfd`.

Comment: Second example memset's only one element. To memset all elemnts in array use: `memset(fds, 0x00, sizeof(fds));`

Comment: @deffel: What "pointers" are you talking about? So far I don't see a single pointer in the code you posted.

Comment: @deffel: Your first code sample is invalid (non-compilable), which kinda destroys the whole question. Let's begin with this: what are you trying to do? How are we supposed to know what's "better" when we don't know what you actually want to do?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with `sizeof(fds[0])/sizeof(fds)`? What do you think this expression evaluates to?

Comment: @AndreyT It seems that I misunderstood the way how a pointer in C works, until now I assumed that an array is a set of pointers pointing to some space in a memory, as in a list, with a size of the element in the array, in this case with the size of struct pollfd. The expression should evaluate to 2 in this case, at least that was my assumption.

Comment: @deffel: I don't see how that explaination explains that the above expresson should evaluate to 2. In any case, the expression that will "evaluate to 2" is actually `sizeof(fds) / sizeof(fds[0])`, i.e. the other way around.

Comment: @deffel: Yes, you've badly misunderstood how arrays and pointers work in C. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); ti explains it quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly `memset` an element of an array, if you want.

Still, memsetting all the consecutive elements with one call is more efficient (The standard guarantees absence of padding between array-elements).

Bugs in your current code:

- your first example misses an address-of-operator, use:

  ```
  memset(&fds[tmp], 0, sizeof *fds);
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  memset(fds+tmp, 0, sizeof *fds);
  ```
- your second example passes the size of a single element instead of the whole array, use:

  ```
  memset(fds, 0, sizeof fds);
  ```

Some side-issues:

- `sizeof` is an operator, no need for parentheses unless you pass a type
- All-bits-zero is not neccessarily the same as `0` for all types, though it holds for modern systems.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether you have already tested your code. But the arguments to `memset` are incorrect.

First method:

Use

```
memset(&fds[tmp], 0x00, sizeof(fds[tmp]));
   //  ^ Missing &
```

instead of

```
memset(fds[tmp], 0x00, sizeof(fds[tmp]));
```

Second method:

Use

```
memset(fds, 0x00, sizeof(fds));
                  //     ^^^ use size of the whole array.
```

instead of

```
memset(fds, 0x00, sizeof(fds[tmp]));
```